# Python multiprocessing manager blocks on start

Tags: python, multiprocessing, deadlock

It seems that the python SyncManager has a problem initializing on my machine

I have the following setup:

in my main startup program:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    theManager = multiprocessManager.Manager()
    stopEvent = theManager.Event()        # Make sure your daemon stops all threads in a clean way

    log = logging.getLogger('central-queue') # maybe move to mp.getlogger?
    # do some log setup with file and stream handlers
    log.info("Creating process safe Object to keep state of testbeds shared over all work processes")
    testbedObjectsPool = theManager.TestbedInfo()

    log.info("Wait a while before starting other processes to init the tbObjPool")
    stopEvent.wait(100)

    log.info("Starting process to watch the input dir")
    jobFinderProcess = jobFinder.JobFinder(inputQueue, stopEvent)
    jobFinderProcess.start()
```

in multiprocessManager.py

```
from multiprocessing.managers import SyncManager

import testbedInfo

class MultiprocessManager(SyncManager):
    pass

MultiprocessManager.register("TestbedInfo", testbedInfo.TestbedInfoPool, proxytype=None)

def Manager():
    #print "MultiprocessManager.Manager"
    m = MultiprocessManager()
    m.start()
    return m
```

in testbedInfo.py

```
class TestbedInfoPool:
    """Gather all info from all testbeds into this class (ie a bunch of TestbedProperties objects)"""
    def __init__(self):
        # Specific to this class
        self._initDatabase() # creates and configures self.db for us
        self.reset()
        blacklistfile = "%s/testbeds_blacklist_dispatcher.txt" % (os.getcwd())
        self.populateTestbeds(blacklistfile) #Store the offline info into self.dictOfIdTestbedObjects Takes about 2 minutes
```

When it is not working, and I press CTRL-C to stop the hanging process I get the following in the debug output.

```
2017-02-08 09:35:10,141 - INFO - xMainProcessx =MainThread= Creating process safe Object to keep state of testbeds shared over all work processes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./dispatchToTestbed.py", line 117, in <module>
    testbedObjectsPool = theManager.TestbedInfo()
  File "/usr/global/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 641, in temp
    token, exp = self._create(typeid, *args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/global/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 541, in _create
    id, exposed = dispatch(conn, None, 'create', (typeid,)+args, kwds)
  File "/usr/global/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 76, in dispatch
    kind, result = c.recv()
KeyboardInterrupt
```

When the processes are started and hanging, I did an strace on both processes just to see what it was doing and got the the expected, I guess:

```
[regressionScheduler]$ strace -p 6202
Process 6202 attached - interrupt to quit
[ Process PID=6202 runs in 32 bit mode. ]
read(7, ^C <unfinished ...>
Process 6202 detached
[regressionScheduler]$ strace -p 6210
Process 6210 attached - interrupt to quit
[ Process PID=6210 runs in 32 bit mode. ]
accept(8, ^C <unfinished ...>
Process 6210 detached

ls -l /proc/6202/fd
lrwx------ 1 mdillen testlab 64 Feb  8 09:33 7 -> socket:[636280798]
ls -l /proc/6210/fd
lrwx------ 1 mdillen testlab 64 Feb  8 09:34 8 -> socket:[636279496]
```

And sometimes, the program starts, does all the initing and continues as expected within 2 minutes.

A py-bt in gdb shows me something like this

```
Using host libthread_db library "/lib64/libthread_db.so.1".
0x009b8430 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
Traceback (most recent call first):
  File "/usr/global/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 202, in accept
    sock, addr = self._sock.accept()
  File "/usr/global/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 241, in accept
    s, self._last_accepted = self._socket.accept()
  File "/usr/global/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 119, in accept
    c = self._listener.accept()
  File "/usr/global/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 153, in serve_forever
    c = self.listener.accept()
  File "/usr/global/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 532, in _run_server
    server.serve_forever()
  File "/usr/global/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 88, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/global/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 232, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/global/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/forking.py", line 99, in __init__
    code = process_obj._bootstrap()
  File "/usr/global/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 104, in start
    self._popen = Popen(self)
  File "/usr/global/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 498, in start
    self._process.start()
  File "testtools/regressionScheduler/multiprocessManager.py", line 16, in Manager
    m.start()
  File "./dispatchToTestbed.py", line 76, in <module>
```

Python version:

```
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Nov 22 2011, 10:48:33)
[GCC 3.4.5 20051201 (Red Hat 3.4.5-2)] on linux2
```

Does anybody have an idea how to debug this further? Or what obvious thing I am missing here?

Some more info I tried to gather:

Main process is doing this according to strace:

```
write(7, "\0\0\0\t#WELCOME#", 13)       = 13
write(7, "\0\0\0'\200\2(NU\6createq\1U\vTestbedInfoq"..., 43) = 43
read(7,
```

strace on Manager process:

```
Process 26350 attached - interrupt to quit
[ Process PID=26350 runs in 32 bit mode. ]
accept(9,
```

lsof main

```
dispatchT 26321 xxxxxx    7u  unix 0xffff8808212260c0      0t0 637197167 socket
```

lsof manager

```
dispatchT 26350 xxxxxx    9u  unix 0xffff88081eea5380      0t0 637197158 /tmp/pymp-v3RwL4/listener-ckeK4Y
```

So does this look like the main process is trying to communicate with the manager process, to start a proxy for TestbedInfo, but that one does not receive it at all?